# Bootstrap / jQuery binding click() event triggering in the same function it is added

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap card which, when clicked on, presents the user with a series of choices, then should return to it's original state.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wgksny22/6/

The card is a basic one:

```
<div class="card border-secondary my-cell">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h6>Card Header</h6>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body my-cell-inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

The following is loaded as a cloneable template `optionsTemplate`:

```
<div id="options-template">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col btn-group-vertical btn-group btn-group-toggle options1" data-toggle="buttons">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">A</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">B</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col btn-group-vertical btn-group btn-group-toggle options2" data-toggle="buttons">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">C</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">D</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The JS that runs the process:

```
        var cell = $('.my-cell');
        var innerCell = $('.my-cell-inner', cell);
        var onClick = function() {
            // the buttons templates
            var edit = optionsTemplate.clone();
            $(".options1 .btn", edit).click(function() {
                $(".options1", edit).hide();
                $(".options2", edit).show();
            });
            $(".options2 .btn", edit).click(function() {
                $(".options2", edit).hide();
                $(innerCell).empty();
                // the problem is here; this is fired as part
                // of the click applying to this function
                $(cell).click(onClick);
            });

            $(".options1", edit).show();
            $(".options2", edit).hide();

            $(cell).off('click');
            $(innerCell).append(edit);
        };
        $(cell).click(onClick);
```

It works until the end of the 2nd selection; as part of the click on the buttons the re-added click binding is processed and it reshows the 1st selection:

- click -> shows A/B -> shows C/D -> shows A/B etc.

Whereas it should be:

- click -> shows A/B -> shows C/D -> finish (ready for another click).

How do I rebind the click in a way that doesn't cause it to be triggered as part of the ongoing click?

I have tried using a jQuery promise but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
jQuery.Deferred().promise().done(function() {
    // this is never reached
    $(cell).click(onClick);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is called 'bubbling' of events. Events are propagated from children up to parents, so adding an event listener onto a parent will lead to that event listener being triggered.

The answer is to block event propagation rather than trying to be clever with functions, which is done using `event.stopPropagation()` in the child even listeners.

Corrected JS:

```
    var cell = $('.my-cell');
    var innerCell = $('.my-cell-inner', cell);
    var onClick = function() {
        // the buttons templates
        var edit = optionsTemplate.clone();
        $(".options1 .btn", edit).click(function() {
            // block event propagation to parent
            event.stopPropagation();
            $(".options1", edit).hide();
            $(".options2", edit).show();
        });
        $(".options2 .btn", edit).click(function() {
            // block event propagation to parent
            event.stopPropagation();
            $(".options2", edit).hide();
            $(innerCell).empty();
        });

        $(".options1", edit).show();
        $(".options2", edit).hide();

        $(innerCell).append(edit);
    };
    $(cell).click(onClick);
```

Answer (score 0):

3 options of jquery click elements:

```
$(".card-header").click(function() {
       $(".options1").show();

    })
 $(".options1 .btn").click(function() {

            $(".options1").hide();
            $(".options2").show();
        });
  $(".options2 .btn").click(function() {
            $(".options2").hide();               
        });
```

At your code always show the two click options loaded at edit variable, i dont know why.

Comment: If you look closely, those elements are essentially discarded from within the click function. This localizes the variables to the click() function because it is (in practise) behaviour bound to multiple cards and not just 1.